# How to compare only time from java.sql.TimeStamp

Tags: java

```
public long compareTwoTimeStamps(Timestamp currentTime, Timestamp oldTime) 
{
  long milliseconds1 = oldTime.getTime();
  long milliseconds2 = currentTime.getTime();
  long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
  long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
  return diffMinutes;
}
```

The above code considers the date as well.
I need to compare the 2 instances of Timestamp and compare only the time portion from Timestamp. The date should not be considered. Whenever I compare it, the comparison also takes date into account.

Comment: Could you show your code? That would help alot to help understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: have you tried something yet???

Comment: Have you searched the rest of Stack Overflow, as there is a plethora of questions and answers on this topic?

Comment: See i want to extract only Time from two different time stamp. Let me show you what i actualy require. Suppose i have a timestamp 1 = 14-04-2015 11.30.00 and another one as timestamp2 = 01-04-2015 11.15.00. So from out of this two i want to just compare only time out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution, using [`getHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours()), [`getMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMinutes()) on the timestamps:

```
public long compareTwoTimeStamps(java.sql.Timestamp currentTime, java.sql.Timestamp oldTime) 
{
    long min1 = oldTime.getHours() * 60 + oldTime.getMinutes();
    long min2 = currentTime.getHours() * 60 + currentTime.getMinutes();
    return min2 - min1;
}
```

or without any deprecated methods:

```
public long compareTwoTimeStamps(java.sql.Timestamp currentTime, java.sql.Timestamp oldTime)
{
    final Calendar oldCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    oldCal.setTime(oldTime);
    long min1 = oldCal.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 60 + oldCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    final Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentCal.setTime(currentTime);
    long min2 = currentCal.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 60 + currentCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    return min2 - min1;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid using deprecated methods

Answer (score 1):

I think that the safest way to do that is by using Calendars:

```
public static boolean sameTime(Date a, Date b) {
    Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
    ca.setTime(a);
    Calendar cb = Calendar.getInstance();
    cb.setTime(b);
    return ca.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == cb.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
            && ca.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == cb.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
            && ca.get(Calendar.SECOND) == cb.get(Calendar.SECOND)
            && ca.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) == cb.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
}
```

This will take into account daylight saving time.

UPDATE:

Oh, and it doesn't use any deprecated method.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to make use of JODA Time's LocalTime:

```
public static boolean sameTime(Date a, Date b) {
    return new LocalTime(a).compareTo(new LocalTime(b)) == 0;
    // equals() or isEquals() may also work depending on your case, you may try
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare only the milliseconds of getTime() representing the time by truncating the date using modulo:

```
private static long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24l;
private static long MILLIS_PER_MINUTE = 1000 * 60l;
public long compareTwoTimeStamps(Timestamp currentTime, Timestamp oldTime) 
{

  long milliseconds1 = oldTime.getTime() % MILLIS_PER_DAY;
  long milliseconds2 = currentTime.getTime() % MILLIS_PER_DAY;
  return milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
  // for minutes:
  // return (milliseconds2 - milliseconds1) / MILLIS_PER_MINUTE;
}
```